# Unable to assign values in a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have declared the structure:

```
typedef struct keyValuePairs{
char* type;
char* key;
char* valueType;
char* value;
} keyValueType;

keyValueType keyValuePairs[1000];
```

And in a function declared the local variables as:

```
char key[500];
char value[500];
```

to hold the key value pair values as:

```
key[i]="abc";
value[i]="xyz"
```

I have assigned these local variables to the global variable as:

```
keyValuepairs[1].key=key.
```

Once i come out of the function, the values assigned in the structure is getting lost. Can someone explain where I am going wrong?
Please note I am fairly new to C.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. Do you mean `key` to be an array of strings, or one key string? As it is, `char key[500]` is _one_ string of length 500 characters, including NULL terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Both **key** and **value** variables are pointers to arrays that are allocated in the stack when you are in the function. After **keyValuepairs[1].key=key** the global variable points to that same place in the stack. After exiting the function, the memory where those arrays were is reused.

I suggest you read up on static vs dynamic allocation in C

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying something along the lines of:

```
typedef struct
{
   char* val;
} A;

A alist[10];

void foo()
{
   char t[10];
   t = "abc";
   alist[0].val = t;
}

int main()
{
   foo();
}
```

First of all, the line

```
t = "abc";
```

is syntactically incorrect. You have to use something like:

```
strcpy(t, "abc");
```

But the most important error is that when you return from `foo`, `alist[0].val` points to an address that is not good any more. To make sure `alist[0].val` points to a valid address, you have to allocate memory from the heap for it and copy the contents of `t` to it.

```
void foo()
{
   char t[10];
   strcpy(t,"abc");
   alist[0].val = malloc(strlen(t)+1);
   strcpy(alist[0].val, t);
}
```

To do a thorough job, you'll have to make sure that you call `free` on that allocated memory at some point before you return from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated memory for **type**, **key**, **valueType** and **value**.
Try static memory allocation :

```
typedef struct keyValuePairs{
char* type[n];
char* key[n];
char* valueType[n];
char* value[n];
}
```

Where **n** is a defined constant